# Get Instance Lifecycle via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, autoscaling

When navigating to the Auto Scaling Groups section of the EC2 Management Console, we can see information about the EC2 instances for each Auto Scaling Groups.

If you take a look at the image below:

[image: 1]

How can I get the value of the field highlighted in green (`Lifecycle`) using the `Instance ID` via the AWS CLI?

I already tried the following command:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids <some instance ID>
```

But that does not provide me with the value in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html)

**Usage:**

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids i-4ba0837f
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "AutoScalingInstances": [
        {
            "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false,
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
            "InstanceId": "i-4ba0837f",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "my-auto-scaling-group",
            "HealthStatus": "HEALTHY",
            "LifecycleState": "InService",
            "LaunchConfigurationName": "my-launch-config"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bonus:**

If you wanna get the LifecycleState value as a string, use the following command :

```
aws autoscaling  describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids INSTANCE_ID --query "AutoScalingInstances[].LifecycleState"  --output text
```